# Getting data from multiple mysql tables WHERE.

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 database tables.

One called files. Which looks like this.

**FILES**

```
USERID FILENAME DEFAULT NETWORKID
88      hello      1      10293
9       bob               
43      opener     1      10293
43      facepa            
9       closer
```

**Second table user networks**

```
USERID NETWORKID 
9       10293
43
```

My current sql query is

```
SELECT file,filename,filetype,size, forename, files.userID
FROM (`files`)
LEFT JOIN users ON users.userID = files.userID
WHERE files.userID = $userID ORDER BY id DESC
```

This currently gets the list of files where userid is 9.

As you can see my userid `9` is also in the usernetworks table and I am connected with network id 10293.

I want to also include in the query, any of the rows that default is 1 and the network id matches to any of those in the usernetworks table with my userID.

So where userid is connected to networkid, also show those results aswell as the ones with userid and no network id.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You should include data for the `users` table as well in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I read your logic correctly, then we can implement it by first left joining `files` to `users` on the condition that the user matches to your user ID.  Then, we can left join again to `users`, this time on the condition that the file record is default, the network IDs match, and the matching user is also your user.

```
SELECT f.*
FROM files f
LEFT JOIN users u1
    ON f.userID = u1.userID AND f.userID = $userID
LEFT JOIN usernetworks u2
    ON f.default = 1 AND
       f.networkid = u2.networkid AND u2.userID = $userID
WHERE
    u1.userID IS NOT NULL OR u2.userID IS NOT NULL;
```

Actually, if you don't plan on selecting any columns from the `users` table then you can probably omit the join to that table completely.  I have left it in as it is true to the original query in your question.

Comment: Almost. Couple of questions - The JOIN users u2, should this be usernetworks?

I ran the query above, and changed the userID to 43 and it still returned the result where default was 1, however user 43 is not connected to networkid 10293, so it shouldnt have shown that file.

Basically the idea is, a user can see files that are set to default 1, with any networkid they are connected to.

Sorry to make it so complicated to understand

Comment: @ScottO'connor Reload your page.  I was missing a third join condition.

Answer (score 1):

I understand you want your files plus the default files in your networks:

```
SELECT userid, filename, networkid 
FROM files
WHERE (userid = $userid 
OR (default = 1 AND networkid in (
   select networkid from network_users where userid = $userid)))
AND filename like :name
```

Your SQL mentions fields that are not in your schema description.

Comment: This looks like what i am after. But getting error :
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= 1 AND networkid in ( select networkid from usernetworks where userid = '9')' at line 4

Comment: This presupposes that we don't need to join to `users`, which may not be true.

Comment: try files.default, default may be a reserved word

Comment: That worked. I'm trying to add this line AND filename LIKE '%".$_GET['query']."%' to it, but keeps telling me i am putting it in the wrong place, any ideas where i would put this (to go in the WHERE statement)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the data on the basis of network id than please use this query

```
SELECT file,filename,filetype,size, forename, files.userID
FROM files a, network b
WHERE a.networkID = b.networkID ORDER BY id DESC
```

.
Hope this will solve your problem

Comment: I don't know if my answer be right, but I know this can't be right.  You're missing at least another join condition, probably an entire join.  And your join syntax is outdated, you should use explicit joins.

Comment: Sorry Tim , may be i didn't get your question properly . can you please brief me again ? and regarding the join it's not outdated what i think . Thanks by the way .